# Can a women/girl posts her video or pictures in hijaab?

Tags: hijab

Can a women/girl posts her video or pictures in hijaab.

Comment: This question requires far more details than you have provided to be properly answerable. Note also that we are *not* a fatwa site.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of the hijab? Is protecting the beauty of a woman from other non-Mahram. Even if you argue that the face is not awrah, but is it allowed for a woman to put herself in a situation where men can stare at her? of course not. Then how can it be allowed to post her photo where 10,20,100 or more men can stare at her on the internet.

> “O Prophet, tell your wives and your daughters and the women of the
> believers to draw their cloaks close round them (when they go abroad).
> That will be better, so that they may be recognised and not annoyed.
> Allah is ever Forgiving, Merciful.”

(Quran 33:59).

However if it's a **private** group where it's **only** for woman, then you may post it. But it's better to be careful. And avoid these Kind of things.

Comment: Thank you for giving your precious time, may Allah bless you .eidul adha mubarak

Comment: Jajakalla hu khair. Eid Mubarak